# ListFragment in a Tabbed Layout not populating from a SQLite DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, fragment

I'm trying to populate 3 ListFragments that are in a Tabbed ViewPager Layout. (Using one of the templates in Android Studio.)

I have been able to successfully put items into the SQLite DB, but I'm having a hard time populating the ListView(s). It would be easy if things weren't static, but the static-ness simply adds to the complexity.

```
package com.example.listapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import static com.example.listapp.ItemData.Items.ORDERB;
import static com.example.listapp.ItemData.Items.TABLE_NAME;
import static com.example.listapp.ItemData.Items.TYPE;
import static com.example.listapp.ItemData.Items.LIST_TEXT;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ItemData ItemsDb;

    String listText = null;



    public static String[] FROM = { LIST_TEXT };
    public static int[] TO = { R.id.list_text };
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"
        + "com.example.listapp" + "/" + TABLE_NAME);

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ItemsDb = new ListData(getApplicationContext());

    Intent saveIntent = getIntent();

    listText = saveIntent.getStringExtra(ItemCreate.EXTRA_MESSAGE);





    if (rlistText != null) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = ItemsDb.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(ORDERB, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(ITEM_TEXT, listText);
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);




    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);



}


public void createItem(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemCreate.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "List1";
            case 1:
                return "List2";
            case 2:
                return "List3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends ListFragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */



    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, FROM, null, null, "_ID DESC");
        ListView listItems = getListView();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.list_item, cursor, FROM, TO, 0);

        listItems.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

The adapter does get properly set, but I get the following error when I run the code:

```
E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.example.listapp
```

What am I doing wrong?